# String assignments at compile time

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string

My iOS app includes a few 100,000 initialization statements like:

```
char* stringData[ 500000];
stringData[ 0] = "abc";
stringData[ 1] = "def";
stringData[ 2] = "ghi";
```

The problem is it takes a few seconds at launch, too much delay before running.
Is there a way to do this at compile time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the text in a file, then embed this file into your application and load it when appropriate:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myText" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
const char *stringData = [data bytes];
```

Comment: But then how do I access, e.g., stringData[ 2] to get "ghi" instantly? Is there an implicit array of string pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Save the strings in Plist file and load the Plist.

Comment: Does *that* solution let me access, e.g., stringData[ 2] within the app's code to get "ghi"?